# Is there a way to tell gcc to ignore ""?

Tags: gcc, arduino, command, eclipse-cdt

When running sloeber (a arduino eclipse plugin build on managed build system of cdt) following command is executed and fails:

```
'Starting combiner'
"D:\eclipse\sloeber\eclipse\/arduinoPlugin/packages/arduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Os -Wl,--gc-sections "-TD:\eclipse\sloeber\eclipse\/arduinoPlugin/packages/Maxim/hardware/arm/1.0.3/system/CMSIS/Device/Maxim/MAX32620/Source/GCC/max32620.ld" "-Wl,-Map,D:\workspaces\junit-workspace\363_max32620_fthr/Release/363_max32620_fthr.map"  -o "D:\workspaces\junit-workspace\363_max32620_fthr/Release/363_max32620_fthr.elf" "-LD:\workspaces\junit-workspace\363_max32620_fthr/Release" -Wl,--cref -Wl,--check-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--entry=Reset_Handler -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=report-all -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,--start-group     .\sloeber.ino.cpp.o   "D:\eclipse\sloeber\eclipse\/arduinoPlugin/packages/Maxim/hardware/arm/1.0.3/system/startup/Build_max32620/system_startup_max32620.a" "D:\eclipse\sloeber\eclipse\/arduinoPlugin/packages/Maxim/hardware/arm/1.0.3/system/MAX32620PeriphDriver/Build/PeriphDriver.a" ""  D:\workspaces\junit-workspace\363_max32620_fthr/Release/arduino.ar  -Wl,--end-group -lm -gcc --specs=nosys.specs  
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: : No such file or directory
```

The problem is caused by a "" in the command. I understand that gcc interprets "" as a file input and does not find the file. As to gcc this is a error which he reports as good as he can.
When I remove the "" all is fine but... the actual command in the makefile is:

```
${A.RECIPE.C.COMBINE.PATTERN.1}  $(LINK_OBJ) ${A.RECIPE.C.COMBINE.PATTERN.2} ${A.ARCHIVE_FILE_PATH} ${A.RECIPE.C.COMBINE.PATTERN.3} ${JANTJE.EXTRA.ALL} ${JANTJE.EXTRA.LINK}
```

To be able to remove the "" I need to expand the command. I used to do so but I'm working on being able to support non-expanded commands to get something else to work.
So I was wondering if I could gently ask gcc to ignore these "expansion leftovers".

Note 1: I am processing files from multiple parties. If a supplier thinks it is a good idea to do something like "${A_VAR}" where A_VAR expands to nothing there is little I can do.

Note 2: I can reproduce this problem in Linux and windows. From the information I see cygwin would handle this case (I didn't test)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question but a way to avoid the issue.

I defined A_VAR as -DIDefinedThisHere

As a result the command contains now `"-DIDefinedThisHere"` instead of `""`
As it is a compilation command gcc accepts the command. As I use a very special define Name, it is very unlikely this will cause issues further downstream.

In my case I picked a define name that points to where the define is defined. There I added some comments on why it is defined.
The idea is that when someone has a bug because A_VAR does not resemble what "it should be", they at least will be routed to the root cause and some explanation why. :-s.

(for the record, that person will probably be me.

Comment: I'm not accepting my own answer as it is a workaround that needs to be done case by case. So I still would like to know the real answer.